# How to use pymiddy on Lambda with python?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, package, middleware

The pymiddy package for AWS Lambda with Python seems to lack a clear example, or I'm having a difficult time figuring it out. How do I use the middleware on Lambda?
Package: https://pypi.org/project/pymiddy/

The code I have so far is

```
from pymiddy import Middy

@Middy
def handler(event, context):
    ...rest of the handler method
```

From the package's example, do I now have to create the "MyCustomMiddleware" class, or can I already an already defined .before method to execute code before the handler() method?

For example, at the bottom of the lambda, I added

```
class MyCustomMiddleware(object):
    def before(self, state):
        print("Got to before step")

    def after(self, state):
        pass

    def error(self, state):
        pass
```

however the before step is not yet being reached. How can I have the .before middleware run before the handler()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

```
from pymiddy import Middy

@Middy
def handler(event, context):
     print('Running lambda')
#    raise ValueError('got exception') # If exception is to be thrown


class MyCustomMiddleware(object):
     def before(self, state):
          print("Running before")

     def after(self, state):
          print("Running after")

     def error(self, state):
          print('Found an exception...')
          print(state['exception'])
    
handler.use(MyCustomMiddleware())
```

As shown in the last line, the method (handler in this case), has to "register" the custom middleware with the `.use()` call. Then the before, after, and error middlewares will run at appropriate times.

Running the above code gave the output:

```
Running before
Running lambda
Running after
```

If the raise ValueError is uncommented, the following is output instead:

```
Running before
Running lambda
Found an exception...
got exception
```